# How come the event handlers on this <li> are not getting invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, event-handling

I have a menu as follows:

```
<button id="button" onclick="DropDown(event)">Drop down the menu</button>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The JavaScript for the menu is:

```
// To close the menu when clicked outside
$(document).click(function() { $('#menu').hide(); });

// When clicking on the items
$('#menu li').click(function () {

    $(document).append('<code>Clicked item!</code>');

});

function DropDown(event) {

    // Position of the menu
    var position = $('#button').offset();

    // Position the menu and slide it down
    $('#menu').css('top',
                   (position.top + $('#button').height() + 4) + 'px')
              .css('left',
                   position.left + 'px')
              .slideToggle();

    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Most of the code works as expected: clicking the button drops down the menu and clicking anywhere makes the menu disappear. **However**, the event handler assigned to the `<li>` items is not getting invoked at all, despite the fact that the `onclick` handler for the `document` is being invoked.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W5SqD/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try attaching the event either in a `$(document).ready()` block or via using the live handler. This will ensure that the event is being attached when the element exists. The below worked for me.

```
// When clicking on the items
$('#menu li').live("click",function () {

    alert("Hello!");
    $(document).append('<code>Clicked item!</code>');

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W5SqD/8/ here is the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/W5SqD/8/

Comment: I'd much sooner go the ready route than the live route (though perhaps you could use delegate instead); live is known to be generally a bad thing to use (one such post discussing this: http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live).  Here's a fiddle waiting for DOM ready: http://jsfiddle.net/W5SqD/17/  To explain, the problem with the original code is that you're querying for `#menu li` before it ever exists in the document.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem - I was really confused until I read your answer.